# .NET core Azure - HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-sql-database

I am trying to publish my .net core web app in Azure, I have managed to publish my project using github actions.
Also I have created an Azure sql database (I configured my asp .net core application with azure sql database using appsettings, but also i added the connection string in the configurations of web app in Azure).

**web.config content**

```
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\Project.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

**In azure service logs I get this error:**

```
HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error
The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.

Most likely causes:
IIS received the request; however, an internal error occurred during the processing of the request. The root cause of this error depends on which module handles the request and what was happening in the worker process when this error occurred.
IIS was not able to access the web.config file for the Web site or application. This can occur if the NTFS permissions are set incorrectly.
IIS was not able to process configuration for the Web site or application.
The authenticated user does not have permission to use this DLL.
The request is mapped to a managed handler but the .NET Extensibility Feature is not installed.

Things you can try:
Ensure that the NTFS permissions for the web.config file are correct and allow access to the Web server's machine account.
Check the event logs to see if any additional information was logged.
Verify the permissions for the DLL.
Install the .NET Extensibility feature if the request is mapped to a managed handler.
Create a tracing rule to track failed requests for this HTTP status code. For more information about creating a tracing rule for failed requests, click here.

Detailed Error Information:
Module     AspNetCoreModuleV2
Notification       ExecuteRequestHandler
Handler    aspNetCore
Error Code     0x00000000
Requested URL      https://sitename:80/
Physical Path      C:\home\site\wwwroot
Logon Method       Anonymous
Logon User     Anonymous

More Information:
This error means that there was a problem while processing the request. The request was received by the Web server, but during processing a fatal error occurred, causing the 500 error.
View more information »

Microsoft Knowledge Base Articles:
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @Larnu, thanks for feedback (i deleted the images)

Comment: But now the errors are missing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was:

in **Azure control panel**

`Appservice -> Settings -> Configuration`

in **Connection strings** section I added the same key and value pair like on my appsettings and
that solved my error!